# How to "bind" a submenu to the mainmenu?

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I know my thread's title is not very well chosen but I do not know how to describe my problem.
Ok back 2 topic:

My application has three menus. Two of them are dependent on each other.
In this example I have three categories: `Cars`, `Trees` and `Students`

In the mainmenu there are three buttons each of them handles one of the three categories.
In the submenu there are three further controls: `Add`, `Remove` and `Print`.

Now if I click on `Cars` I want the application to activate all three buttons in the submenu so that the user is able to manage his/her cars.
Therefor there will be a table containing all existing data but this does not matter at the moment.

My problem is now how to get to know which category button was pressed by the user? There is only one submenu and if the user hits the `Add`-Button the application has to know to which category it should add a new entry.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use 3 different commands, but want to know which category it was chosen from.

If so, then you can use a CommandParameter to indicate the category - the command parameter data will be passed into `CanExecute()`/`Execute()` when they are called.

(ignore the repeated ApplicationCommands.Cut below...I used them just for testing in KAXAML....just replace that with either the Add, Remove, or Print commands you defined).

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Menu>
       <MenuItem Header="Cars">
        <MenuItem Header="Add" Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" CommandParameter="Cars"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Remove" Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" CommandParameter="Cars"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Print" Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" CommandParameter="Cars"/>
      </MenuItem>
       <MenuItem Header="Trees">
        <MenuItem Header="Add" Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" CommandParameter="Trees"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Remove" Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" CommandParameter="Trees"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Print" Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" CommandParameter="Trees"/>
      </MenuItem>
       <MenuItem Header="Students">
        <MenuItem Header="Add" Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" CommandParameter="Students"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Remove" Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" CommandParameter="Students"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Print" Command="ApplicationCommands.Cut" CommandParameter="Students"/>
      </MenuItem>
  </Menu>
</Page>
```